# Page does not occupy 100% of the print page

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm reviewing some screens of a system and I came across a problem. The old page was made using the  tag for styling, but it had several nested  tags, maintenance was unsustainable.

I decided to migrate the screen to bootstrap using the classes to keep the default page, in addition, I kept the default sizes (height and width) from the previous page, since I cannot change this default.

After completing the stylization I came across this problem, during printing, the page does not completely occupy the printing sheet. I've tried numerous alternatives and none of them worked, I find myself at a dead end and I don't want to return all the work to square 0.
[image: Print Screen]

For contractual reasons I cannot paste the code here, but I will try to put a part of it as an illustration.

```css
.style3 {
            font-size: xx-small;
        }
        
        .style4 {
            font-size: x-small;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .borda {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-left: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            border-right: 1px solid;
            border-color: #808080 !important;
        }
        
        .style8 {
            font-size:small;
            font-family: Arial;
            height: 4px;
        }

        .row15 {
            font-size: xx-small;
            min-height: 15px;
            max-height: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda" style="height:115px;width:120px;">
      <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="borda" style="height:115px;width:375px;">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <p><label Style="font-size: small"></label></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <p><label Style="font-size: medium">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</label></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <span style="font-size: medium;">Nota Fiscal Eletrônica de Serviço</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <span class="style3"> Município: 
            <label>PRAIA LINDA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>9</label>
            &nbsp; UF: <label>BA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>31</label>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="borda style3" style="height:115px;width:210px;">
      <div class="row m-0 mt-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Data/Hora:
          <label class="style3"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Nº da Nota:
          <label class="style3">12</label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label cssClass="style3">0</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Ass. Digital:
          <label>3315646564</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Forma de Pagamento:
          <label>VISTA</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda" style="height:112px;width:120px;">
      <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="borda" style="height:112px;width:585px;padding:1.5px;">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="background-color:#80ff80;">
          <strong class="style8">PRESTADOR DO SERVIÇO</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Nome/Razão Social:
          <label>AAAAAAAA</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Nome Fantasia:
          <label style="Width:384px;">AAAAA</label>
          Aliq.:<label></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Endereço:
          <label style="Width:405px">RUA A</label>
          CEP:
          <label>44444-444</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but that didn't work, the fields kept overwriting each other and it looked really weird

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of columns in % instead of px like this:

```css
.style3 {
   font-size: xx-small;
 }            
.style4 {
   font-size: x-small;
   font-weight: bold;
 }         
.borda {
   border-bottom: 1px solid;
   border-left: 1px solid;
   border-top: 1px solid;
   border-right: 1px solid;
   border-color: #808080 !important;
 }
.borda11, .borda21 {
   width: 120px;
 }
.borda12 {
   width: 375px;
 }
.borda13 {
   width: 210px;
 }
.borda22 {
   width: 585px;
 }            
.style8 {
   font-size:small;
   font-family: Arial;
   height: 4px;
 }
.row15 {
   font-size: xx-small;
   min-height: 15px;
   max-height: 15px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda borda11" style="height:115px;">
      <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="borda borda12" style="height:115px;">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <p><label Style="font-size: small"></label></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <p><label Style="font-size: medium">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</label></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <span style="font-size: medium;">Nota Fiscal Eletrônica de Serviço</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <span class="style3"> Município: 
            <label>PRAIA LINDA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>9</label>
            &nbsp; UF: <label>BA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>31</label>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="borda borda13 style3" style="height:115px;">
      <div class="row m-0 mt-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Data/Hora:
          <label class="style3"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Nº da Nota:
          <label class="style3">12</label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label cssClass="style3">0</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Ass. Digital:
          <label>3315646564</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
          Forma de Pagamento:
          <label>VISTA</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda borda21" style="height:112px;">
      <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="borda borda22" style="height:112px;padding:1.5px;">
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="background-color:#80ff80;">
          <strong class="style8">PRESTADOR DO SERVIÇO</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Nome/Razão Social:
          <label>AAAAAAAA</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Nome Fantasia:
          <label style="Width:384px;">AAAAA</label>
          Aliq.:<label></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
          Endereço:
          <label style="Width:405px">RUA A</label>
          CEP:
          <label>44444-444</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I cannot change the look before printing, that is, there is a screen pattern that needs to be maintained, but when printing it needs to occupy the entire sheet.

Comment: @mmirbekian The strange thing is that before it was in a table with the same dimensions and it was printing correctly. Including table within another table, tags without closure, nested tags that shouldn't. But when printing it was coming out right.

Comment: @mmirbekian Thanks again, but I'm avoiding the <table> tag. I want to do exactly as in the code snippet I put. I even managed to make the width reasonable, but the height is still missing. I just can't understand why with the <table> tag it works and without it it doesn't work.

Comment: @SillasSenna I just edited my answer.. Please review .. Just check the print size

Answer (score 0):

I made the size as the maximum that an A4 paper would allow in one page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid biggest">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda" style="height:115px;width:120px;">
        <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="borda" style="height:115px;width:375px;">
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <p><label Style="font-size: small"></label></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <p><label Style="font-size: medium">Secretaria Municipal da Fazenda</label></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <span style="font-size: medium;">Nota Fiscal Eletrônica de Serviço</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <span class="style3"> Município:
            <label>PRAIA LINDA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>9</label>
            &nbsp; UF: <label>BA</label>
            &nbsp;Código: <label>31</label>
          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="borda style3" style="height:115px;width:210px;">
        <div class="row m-0 mt-2">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
            Data/Hora:
            <label class="style3"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
            Nº da Nota:
            <label class="style3">12</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label cssClass="style3">0</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
            Ass. Digital:
            <label>3315646564</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 text-left" style="height:26px;">
            Forma de Pagamento:
            <label>VISTA</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center borda" style="height:112px;width:120px;">
        <strong class="style3">NOTA FISCAL CANCELADA</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="borda" style="height:112px;width:585px;padding:1.5px;">
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" style="background-color:#80ff80;">
            <strong class="style8">PRESTADOR DO SERVIÇO</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
            Nome/Razão Social:
            <label>AAAAAAAA</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
            Nome Fantasia:
            <label style="Width:384px;">AAAAA</label> Aliq.:
            <label></label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 pl-1 row15">
            Endereço:
            <label style="Width:405px">RUA A</label> CEP:
            <label>44444-444</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    * {
      .style3 {
        font-size: xx-small;
      }
      .style4 {
        font-size: x-small;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .borda {
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-color: #808080 !important;
      }
      .style8 {
        font-size: small;
        font-family: Arial;
        height: 4px;
      }
      .row15 {
        font-size: xx-small;
        min-height: 15px;
        max-height: 15px;
      }
      margin: 0;
      padding:0;
    }
    /*
  .big{
  width: 595px;
  height: 842px;
  background: yellow;
}*/
    
    .biggest {
      border: 2px dashed black;
      width: 2480px;
      height: 1465px;
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```